# Java insert data into database with Foreign Key

Tags: java, database, foreign-keys

So I am creating a small application for a football organisation that needs to be able to add teams to the database.

My database has the following ERD:

[image: Database ERD]

I have the following code to add teams to my database:

```
public void toevoegenPloeg(Ploeg ploeg) throws DBException, ApplicationException {
    //connectie tot stand brengen
    System.out.println(ploeg.getTrainerID());
    try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection();) {
        //statement opstellen
        try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into ploeg (naam, niveau, trainer_id) values(?,?,?)");) {
            statement.setString(1, ploeg.getNaam());
            statement.setString(2, ploeg.getNiveau());
            statement.setInt(3, ploeg.getTrainerID());
            statement.execute();


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new DBException("SQL-exception in de toevoegenPloeg-methode - statement" + ex);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new DBException("SQL-exception in de toevoegenPloeg-methode - connectie " + ex);
    }

}
```

It has to be possible to add teams without a trainer.
Like this:

```
PloegTrans PT = new PloegTrans();
PersoonTrans PeT = new PersoonTrans();

Ploeg ploeg1 = new Ploeg();
ploeg1.setNiveau("U9");
PT.ploegToevoegen(ploeg1);
```

Trainer_id is an int and because I haven't defined the trainer_id.
The trainer_id becomes the default of an int, 0.

But then I get a Foreign Key exception, because the database looks for a trainer with id 0.

How can I overcome this?

How can I initialize my int as a "null"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `statement.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` or construct the statement as `insert into ploeg (naam, niveau) values(?,?)`, so `trainer_id` will default to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

On the POJO's side, the trainer ID should be a `java.lang.Integer`, not a primitive `int`, in order to allow `null`s. On the JDBC side, you could use `setObject` instead of `setInt`, which does accept `null`s:

```
// getTrainerID() returns either an Integer instance or null
statement.setObject(3, ploeg.getTrainerID());
```